# How to get the code from a cloud object

Tags: wolfram-cloud

I have a cloud object created a long long ago:

```
CloudObject["https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/ed0a98e0-0915-4f84-bd5b-448980f5b69c"]
```

But I don't remember how did I create it. I want to get its source code now. Considering I'm the creator, is this possible?

Comment: What happens if you run `CloudImport[CloudObject["https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/ed0a98e0-0915-4f84-bd5b-448980f5b69c"], "Text"]`?

Comment: @J.M. Get nothing. :)

Comment: What do you mean by source code? Can you provide an example of `CloudDeploy` and the result you'd like to extract from returned `CloudObject`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give what I want

```
    Import[CloudObject["https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/ed0a98e0-0915-4f84-
bd5b-448980f5b69c"],"Text"]
```

> `FormFunction[FormObject[<|"yourexpression" -> <|"Interpreter" ->`
>   `"Expression"|>|>], Identity, "PNG"]`